# Find number of business hours worked on a task

Tags: sql

I am looking to calculate number of actual hours worked on a particular task. Clock start once tag(activity_tag='Add_Tag' has been applied. Clock stops when progress = 'Blocked', it start again when progress='In Progress'. Task can have any number of status change. So I am confused where to start , how to exclude 'Blocked' time etc. Any pointer would be very helpful.

Here is some sample data.

[image]

Thanks a lot for your help!!!

Comment: I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Comment: Do you want to do this using query or code?

Comment: Sample data is better presented as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a cursor and write you business logic there to calculate total hours for a particular task number. You can change this according to your requirement.

Its checking the previous value of activity and progress and on the basis of that deciding whether to consider the difference of CreateTime or not.

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;
DECLARE @Activity varchar(50);
declare @Progress varchar(50);
declare @CreateTime datetime;
DECLARE c_task CURSOR FOR SELECT Activity, Progress, CreateTime FROM TaskTable where TaskNumber=123;
declare @totalMinutes int;
declare @lastTime datetime;
declare @lastActivity varchar(50);
declare @lastProgress varchar(50);

SET @totalMinutes=0;
SET @lastTime = getdate();
set @lastActivity = '';
set @lastProgress = '';

OPEN c_task;
FETCH next from c_task into @Activity, @Progress, @CreateTime
   WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
   Begin
      if((@Activity = 'Add_Tag' or @Progress='In Progress') and (@lastActivity!='Add_Tag'))
      Begin
        set @lastActivity = @Activity;
        set @lastProgress =  @Progress;
        set @lastTime = @CreateTime;
      End
      Else if((@Progress='Blocked' or @Progress='Closed') and (@lastActivity = 'Add_Tag' or @lastProgress='In Progress'))
      Begin
        print @lastActivity;
        print @lastProgress;
        print @lastTime;
        set @lastActivity = @Activity;
        set @lastProgress =  @Progress;
        set @totalMinutes += datediff(minute, @lastTime, @CreateTime);
        print @totalMinutes;
      End
      FETCH next from c_task into @Activity, @Progress, @CreateTime
   END; 
   CLOSE c_task; 
   DEALLOCATE c_task;

   select @totalMinutes/60;
```